# Program running for long time for n>50

Tags: c++, recursion

I have tried a program to find nth fibonacci number using recursion in [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) compiler(web)

For input `n` `greater than 40 or 50` it takes more time to run ,is there any problem in my code or any optimization suggested. Open to any suggestions.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



long int fib(int a)

{
    if(a<=1) return a;
    return fib(a-1)+fib(a-2);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<fib(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should plot how many calls to `fib()` end up being made based on `n` and see what happens. You can do this by hand for `n` up to 5 and it will become very obvious.

Comment: This implementation is terribly inefficient because of the double recursive call. To calculate fib(50), you first calculate fib(49) **and** fib(48) separately. This is twice the work. Then to calculate fib(49), you calculate fib(48) and fib(47). Notice at this point, you've calculated fib(48) twice. In the end, you're going to do an exponential number of computations.